# Menu bar not appearing on external display

Tags: macos, menu-bar, sonoma

My menu bar on my extended screen is never shown now. I've only noticed this recently after restarting my machine. It has always been there. It works ok on my main display if I change my main display to my external screen.

[image]

I am using macOS Sonoma 14.2.1

Automatically hide and show the menu bar set to "In Full Screen Only"[image]

Any way to get it back on my extended display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's dependant on the setting of 'Displays have separate Spaces' in System Settings > Desktop & Dock [right at the bottom].

Without separate Spaces the menu bar will only ever appear on the Primary screen [your displays will also shift Spaces as a pair]. With it on then the menu will appear at the top of whichever Space is active [Spaces can be called individually per display].

Comment: That was it thank you so much